# Kotlin gradle can't find a csv file in my resources folder

Tags: kotlin, gradle, path

I am new to Kotlin and I build a project in IntelliJ IDEA via gradle, I have a test which requires me to open a csv file, which I have put in my resources folder. But I cannot write the correct path to it in my Test function. Here's my code:

```kotlin
class Tov {

    @Test
    fun `Fermi Gas Equations With Inverse EOS`() {
        csvOpen("resources/output.csv", 3).forEach {
            print(it)
        }
}
```

csvOpen is a function of mine in my kotlin folder

```kotlin
fun csvOpen(csvFilePath: String, columnIndex: Int): Sequence<Double> {
    return File(csvFilePath)
        .useLines { lines ->
            lines.drop(1) // Skip the header if there is one
                .map { it.split(",")[columnIndex].toDouble() }
        }
}
```

What should I do, the file is in the resource folder of the test folder btw.

I have tried absolute path as follows:
`~/src/main/test/resources/output.csv`

Comment: On the JVM, resources are accessed via `Class#getResource(String)`, `Class#getResourceAsStream(String)`, etc.